# Django Templates Formsets with Foreign Key Lookup

Tags: python, django, django-templates

hoping for some guidance around my below problem with displaying reverse lookup field in a template inside formsets.

Maintenance Item Model

```
class Maintenance_Item(CommonInfo):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Checklist Model

```
class MaintenanceCheckList(CommonInfo):
    CHOICES = (
        ('P','Compliant'),
        ('F','Non-Compliant'),
    )

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Maintenance_Item, on_delete=PROTECT, related_name='item_name')
    is_compliant = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices= CHOICES, default=CHOICES[0][0])

    def __int__(self):
        return self.item
```

**EDIT Form**

```
class MaintenanceCheckListComplianceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    is_compliant = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=MaintenanceCheckList.CHOICES,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MaintenanceCheckList
        fields = ('item','is_compliant',)
```

**END EDIT**
The current template

```
<form class="" method='post'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.management_form }}
      <table class="table my-0" id="dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Maintenance Items</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for sub_form in form %}
          <tr>
            {% for i in sub_form.item_name.all %}
              <td>Item: {{ i.name }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
                {{ sub_form.item|add_class:"form-select" }}<p>
              </p>{{ sub_form.is_compliant }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>   
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class='pt-sm-2'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Currently, I have generic formset view which creates an row for each item in the Maintenance_Item which works brilliant and generates the formset view as shown.
[image: Formset of Maintenance Items]

The challenge, I have is I want to hide the ModelChoice fields (I can do that easily with a Widget), and just display the friendly name in the ModelChoice field as a simple Text Label in the template.

*Note setting disabled won't work because POST ignores disabled fields (already troubleshooted using that)*

Comment: please post your forms.py

Comment: @JuConte added into post as requested

Comment: I've exprimented using Get_context data and passing that to my view, while i can get some data showing, there isn't logic to display the correct name on each item


    `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        info_context = [{'item': obj['id'], 'is_compliant': 'F', 'name': obj['name'], 'description': obj['name_description']} for obj in Maintenance_Item.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'name_description')]
        context['info'] = info_context
        return context`